# Css label not going full width on multiplelines

Tags: css

[image]

I have no way of explaining this better.

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4vosLvxg/3/

```
<div class="col-md-12 " style="display: flex;">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="tooltips">
         <input type="checkbox"> Système d'avertissement de collision 
        et frein de secours automatique
      </label>
  </div>
  <a class="tool-tip"></a>
</div>
```

The CSS is irelevant since I've tried all known combinations.

What I (my client) want(s) is to make the infobutton appear near the text (label) but not inside the label.

To reproduce the issue one must resize the window till the last word goes on a new line. Then he will see that the label's width won't be as long as the longest line.

Hours wasted: ~14

Any suggestion/hack will do.

**EDIT:**
This explains it better:

[image]

Comment: can you provide an image of your desired output?

Comment: @LouieAlmeda I've edited my post with the real production image

Comment: @Vucko applying inline-block or inline doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Your question title is wrong. Your problem is that `label` **does** go full width (that's why the `i` is so far right).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu it depends on how you look at the problem :) IMO it doesn't go full width as the full width would fit the content and it wouldn't overflow.

Comment: Not really, Tudor. Web is a very exact science, there are no ambiguities. The width of the label is blueish + greenish (in your picture). This accounts for the position of the tooltip trigger. Understanding this is the first step towards controlling the position of the tooltip trigger, and it's not an optional step. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you are asking for. Please note the change in `html` markup:

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.checkbox label {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox a.tool-tip {
  width: 14px;
  background: url("http://www.chromachklist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/InfoButton0.png") right no-repeat;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tooltips a.tool-tip {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: initial;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 " style="display: flex;">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <a class="tool-tip"></a>
    <label class="tooltips">
      <a class="tool-tip"></a>
      <input type="checkbox"> Système d'avertissement de collision et frein de secourssssssssss automatique
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question! For now I will partially use the first solution you have provide (which was the original way in which it was implemented). The reason I didn't use this solution before is that when clicking on the info-button, it toggles the checkbox.  I will not accept your answer though because it doesn't answer my question. If you look at the second screenshot, you will see that the label extends way beyond the containing text.

Comment: If you inspect the containing text, it's all the way till the `i`. Add background to it and you will see it does.

Comment: In your example, it does but in my example, the label extends way beyond the last word.

Comment: I updated answer and removed the previous versions. I assume this is what you wanted in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! :D